# Embed tag in html is not working in fedora

Tags: html

I want to add Music file in a HTML Page, I used the embed tag of html

.

But it is not working in the Fedora-FireFox.
I just need steps for How to do it? also, is there any website where i can check it in working.

regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Answer (score 0):

Music files are not supported in HTML, maybe you should look for jPlayer (or just Google like I did...)

edit:
I see that Jplayer uses HTML5, which is still not supported in many browsers, maybe you could better take a look at [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

Comment: Hi harmen,

Thanx 4 ur quick reply. Actually i need a sound whenever my certain div is get updated. is it possible on fedora? Actually i check it on mac and i found it working, but not on fedora.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed audio using the `audio` tag, you need a browser that is HTML 5 compliant like Firefox 3.5. This might not be the case of the one you use on Fedora.

Try looking up a flash audio player instead, there are [tons of them](http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/) out there.

Comment: Hi,
I am using fedora 10 with Firefox 3.0.15 and Mozilla/5.0. Is it insufficient to play embed tag successfully?

Comment: If it doesn't work, then it's not supported. You need firefox 3.5+ or something like that

Comment: But anyways it's better to use a flash player, because most of internet users don't have a recent browser